# How to use real-time configurations in an ASP.NET application without restaring it?

Tags: asp.net, configuration, web-config, filesystemwatcher

I have an asp.net application which uses session for user management. So if the application is restarted users will loose their works.

I have some components used by this asp.net application and those components (class libraries in `Bin` folder) have configurations. I want to save configurations of those components somewhere and change them from back-end (administration panel) and the components use the updated configs but still application should not be restarted (changing web.config will result in application restart).

How can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put all your configurations in any xml file.  This way even of you change the configuration at runtime, the application will not be restarted.  Since any changes in web.config will restart the application.

### EDIT:

I found something, you can add an `app.config` to your web application and map the app.config to get the settings from there.

```
ExeConfigurationFileMap exConfigFile = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
exConfigFile.ExeConfigFilename = Server.MapPath("app.config");
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(exConfigFile, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

// you can get the appSettings configuration in the app.config by this
string testConfig = config.AppSettings.Settings["Test"].Value;
```

Comment: XML files can easily be downloaded and reveal sensitive data (*.config is more secure). also I need a file-system-watcher for being notified of any changes. I sounds like reconstructing the wheel and I believe `System.Configuration` should cover this case, but I don't know how.

Comment: renaming the xml file to `*.config` cannot be downloaded anymore, but that doesn't cover the `System.Configuration` that you want.

Comment: it is possible to use the `System.Configuration` for any `*.config` files that you use to store configuration settings. See my edits.

Answer (score 0):

What about storing sessions in a SQL Server database (or at least storing them out-of-process)?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.sessionstatemode.aspx